# Android: How to start an activity at a specified time?

Tags: android, timer, android-activity, clock

I'm making an alarm clock of sorts, and I was wondering what the best way to start an activity at a certain time would be. Would it be using the broadcast service or...

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to register an Intent that will fire at the specified time.